# Using ProcessBuilder in a Silex Project

Tags: php, silex, symfony-process

I am wanting to use the Symfony\Component\Process\ProcessBuilder class and can see that it is included as part of the Silex codebase within the vendors folder. I am using the Silex phar file and assume that because I can readily instantiate other Symfony components like Request, Response and so on that it will correctly locate the file to include when I use the full namespace.

```
$foo = new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request(); //works fine
```

However, when I try and create and instance of it using:

```
$foo = new Symfony\Component\Process\ProcessBuilder(); //class not found
```

It gives me a class not found error. Does anyone know why this is and how I can use this class from the Silex phar without including the component seperately within my project?

Comment: Looks like I can answer my own question here. I have looked in the Compiler.php file in Silex and it looks like the Process component is not included the the Silex phar file.

Comment: That is correct. You can post it as an answer to the question and then accept your own answer. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the Process Symfony component is not included in the compiled Silex phar file.